# How to filter array of objects where object has another array?

Tags: javascript

We have variable **currentCategoryId** and array of object

```
[
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
]
```

for example `const currentCategoryId = 12` and need to return new filter array

```
[
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
]
```

or

```
const currentCategoryId = 16
```

return

```
[
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
]
```

**My code**

```
 const postsByCategory = posts.filter(({ categories }) =>
    categories.filter(
      categoryId => categoryId === 
       currentCategoryId
    )
)
```

returned

```
[
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
]
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: please check [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple to implement with the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function.

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
];

const currentCategoryId = 12

const result = arr.filter((arr) => {
    return arr.categories.includes(currentCategoryId);
});

console.log(result);
```

The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided callback function.
The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate. In this example, it checks if the `categoryId` is included in the categories field of the current array element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **.filter** in the inner array for categories , you should use the **.includes** method to check if the categoryId exists . A simple and generic solution using filter and includes array methods , pass array and the categoryId . It returns the filtered data

```js
var array  =[
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
]

function filterData(data,categoryId){
  return data.filter(obj => obj.categories.includes(categoryId));
}

console.log(filterData(array,12))
console.log(filterData(array,16))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**: Using the the Array helpers (prototypes) `.filter()` and `.includes()` is the simplest and easiest way to return an array of all elements in the data array that include and category number you are looking for:

```js
var data = [
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
];
console.log('searching for items with category 12...');
console.log(data.filter(a => a.categories.includes(12)));
console.log('searching for items with category 16...');
console.log(data.filter(a => a.categories.includes(16)));
```

**Solution #2**: Don't be this one-liner guy/gal even though it works by returning an array of name value pairs from the data array (using `Object.entries()`) and then reducing that to an array of values from the data array that *only* contain the category number you want (using `Array.prototype.indexOf()`).

```js
var data = [
    { id: 18, title: "hello world!", categories: [12, 18] },
    { id: 12, title: "hi hi hi", categories: [12] },
    { id: 65, title: "hi there!", categories: [16] },
];

// Nasty one-liner
const fcbid = (arr, id) => Object.entries(arr).reduce((a,c) => ((c[1].categories.indexOf(id) != -1) && a.push(c[1]), a), []);

console.log('searching 12...');
console.log(fcbid(data, 12));
console.log('searching 16...');
console.log(fcbid(data, 16));
```